# How to manage state in Edit Modal Form with Submit Function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I appear to be going around in circles on this one.

I have created an Edit Form that is featured within a modal. This is accessed via a button that sits on a display page. The contents of the display page is dictated by a user menu. The display page component passes the object being displayed to the Edit model to be edited.

Please note that I am yet to tie the app into the backend so the form submission handle lacks any PUT call or error handling. Instead I am emulating this via a console.log.

I have included a portion of my Edit Form code as there are many fields.

```
import {react,useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import './EditPreGameModel.css'
import DropSearch from './DropSearch/DropSearch'

export default function EditPreGameModal( { open, onClose, preGameTrade} ) {

  const [PreGame, setPreGame] = useState(preGameTrade)

  const handleChange=(e)=> {
    setPreGame({...PreGame,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})

  }



  const submitHandler=(e)=>{

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(PreGame)
    onClose()
  }
  

    if(!open) return null


  return (

    <div className='Overlay_style'></div>

    <div className='EditPreGameModalCont'>
    
    <div className='EditPreGameHeaders'>
      <header className='PreGameName'>{preGameTrade.Tradename}</header>
      <header className='editHeader'>PreGame Edit</header>
      
    </div>
    <form className='preGameForm' onSubmit={(e)=>submitHandler(e)}>
      <div className='FirstEditItems'>
        <label>Status:</label>

        <select className="editDropdown" name="Status" value={PreGame.Status} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="PreGame">PreGame</option>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="InGame">InGame</option>
        </select>
       
        <label>Instrument:</label>
        <select className="editDropdown" name="Instrument" value={PreGame.Instrument} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="FX">FX</option>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="Crypto">Crypto</option>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="Equities">Equities</option>
        </select>

        <label>Ticker:</label>
        <DropSearch  ticker={PreGame.Instrument="FX"? PreGame.FXSymbol : PreGame.Instrument="Crypto"? PreGame.Crypto : PreGame.StockSymbol}></DropSearch>
 
      </div>
      <div className='SecondEditItems'>
        <label>Category:</label>
        <select className="editDropdown" name="BuySell" value={PreGame.BuySell} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="Buy">Buy</option>
          <option className="DropOptions" value="Sell">Sell</option>
        </select>           
      </div>
    

      <div className='EditControl'> 
        <button type='submit' className='EditControlButton'>Submit</button>
        <button className='EditControlButton' onClick={onClose}>Exit</button>
      </div>

    </form>


  </div>
 

  )
}
```

The challenge I am facing is begins with the copy I am making via:

```
const [PreGame, setPreGame] = useState(preGameTrade)
```

This receives the object to be edited and creates a copy to be edited by the user prior to being submitted. This is done to stop edits occurring directly on the original. The logic here was that I didn't want edits to be passed back up to display page without a submission.  This stops edits showing even when the user cancels the edit halfway through. The ambition was to have the user build the copy PreGame and commit that to a PUT request. The display component would then request a refresh of the data and present it back to the User.

However, this results in another issue. Selecting and Editing the first item seems fine but if the user navigates the menu, selects another object and clicks Edit, the object held within PreGame remains to be the original rather than the new. The fields remain tied to the original.

One final note - the Edit Form header is the name of the object and this isn't intended to be editable in this version. As a result I just call the name of the original object. This changes fine whilst navigating through different objects.

Am I approaching this incorrectly? Do I need a useEffect() ref to listen for changes in preGameTrade and then call the setPreGame()?

Thanks, any help is great appreciated.

Comment: When you reference the "original rather than the new" pregame object, do you mean the first instance of PreGame that was passed into props?

Comment: Yes Jason, on startup I have set the preGame object to be the first in the users list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the issue wherein your edit-form is not being sensitive to user selection.

you can add a useEffect block sensitive to *preGameTrade* prop

```
const [PreGame, setPreGame] = useState(preGameTrade)
useEffect(() => {
  setPreGame(preGameTrade);
}, [preGameTrade]);
```

Explanation:
the state variable will not get updated on changing the props passed to the component by itself. To do this we need a useEffect block.

Comment: Thanks Krishanu - I went around in circles and found the same solution. It is great to know this is actually the way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the object that's passed into props. If you want to edit the now modified instance again, you'll need to call a function that's passed into the editing component. We can call it the "update function".

That update function can be called, in your case, inside the `submitHandler` function - after the success of the PUT request. The update function is called in the child component, but it's execution happens on the parent.

This is called "lifting state".
Here's some snippets that I think capture the idea.

```
// The child component
const Child = (preGame, updatePregame) => {
  const submitHandler=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(PreGame)
    updatePregame(PreGame)
    onClose()
  }
};
```

```
// The parent component
const Parent = () => {
  const updatePreGame = (pregame) => {
    // Update the instance of pregame with the values
    // from the copy modified in Child.
  };

  return (
    <Child preGame={pregame} updatePregame={updatePregame} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason - I completely see this is lacking and will address. You have raised another point for me to tackle as the pregame object that you identify above is in fact another stateful object tied to the user menu selection. My original issue I believe still remains. Sorry if my explanation was poor. It would seem my PreGame copy never updates when passed a new object. So if the user selects object 1 then edits and submits, when object 2 is selected and edited PreGame is still tied to the first and the second object fields are not presented. Unless I am missing the point? Thanks again

Comment: Chris, there's a related concept call props drilling (along with state lifting). These need to be done because of one way data binding. It's just something to get used to in React. Your code is probably fine. If this approach solves your problem, please accept my answer; if not LMK.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jason.  I used useEffect as described below and it solved my original issue. I will use your suggestions above also. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the update. I believe if the component with the form was getting unmounted, you wouldn't need the useEffect because each time the form component gets mounted it creates the state variable with the latest props. I'm think in your case, the component is not getting unmounted and must be kept in sync with the parent (which is a use case for useEffect).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way you are adding properties to the object

````
 setPreGame({...PreGame,`${e.target.name}`:e.target.value})

} ```
````

Comment: Thanks Leana - I have made the update to check but the issue still remains. To confirm the main question is not about saving the edits onto the object to be viewed in the display component (although this is missing). The challenge is presenting another object to the user in the edit form when they make another selection. It appears my PreGame remains tied to the original preGameTrade that was passed on startup. Thanks